# How does this variable get changed?

Tags: java, arrays, variables

The following code produces this output:

> aaab -> aabb -> abbb -> bbbb

My goal is to get it to look like this:

> aaab -> aaba -> abaa -> baaa

But I am having a hard time figuring out why I am getting this result.

```
    String abcd = 'abcd';
    int l=3;
    byte[] word=new byte[]{abcd[0],abcd[0],abcd[0],abcd[0]};
    System.out.println(new String(word)); // print: aaaa
    while (l >= 0) {
        byte[] present=word; // !!!
        present[l + 1 - (l - (--l))] = abcd[1];
        System.out.println(new String(present)); // print: aaab -> aabb -> abbb -> bbbb
    }
    System.out.println(new String(word)); // print: bbbb
```

If i change this line(5): `byte[] present=word;`

to `byte[] present=new byte[]{abcd[0],abcd[0],abcd[0],abcd[0]};`

then I get the desired output.  Why is this happening?

Comment: `byte[] present=word;` this does not make a copy of the array - this causes `present` to reference the same array as `word`.

Comment: i not write: word=present, i write: present=word. Then present must changed, not word.

Comment: @satiate Except both `word` and `present` will be references to the same array. Changing `word[0]` will also be reflected by `present[0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
byte[] present=word;
```

simply copy reference and any modification to present are reflected to word: in other word, write to present will apply the same modification to word.
You have to do an System.arraycopy() to make a deep copy

Comment: Thanks. I went to read about System.arraycopy and came across another version:  `byte[] present=word.clone();`

Answer (score 7):

`present` is being set to a *reference* to `word`. The values in `word` are not being copied. So when you change values in `present`, it's really changing the variable that `present` "refers" to: `word`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are giving two references for the same object in this line:

```
byte[] present=word;
```

You don't clone the word object to use it for others things.

Answer (score 2):

Because arrays is a reference type variables. So when you do

```
byte[] present=word
```

you just create a new reference to the same object. Changing the object anyhow, of course, reflects in all references.
That's it.

Answer (score 2):

> "Why word is changed?"

Because you changed it! Where? Here:

```
byte[] present=word;
present[l + 1 - (l - (--l))] = abcd[1];
```

Since you used `=` to initlaize `present`, it refernces to `word`.
And the seconde line changes the value of both `present` and `word`.

Whe the seconde version work?

```
byte[] present=new byte[]{abcd[0],abcd[0],abcd[0],abcd[0]};
```

Because you creating a **fresh new** array instead of referncing to the old one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that present is a pointer to word and that's why it's changing it.  You may want to copy it by doing something like this:

```
byte[] present = new byte[word.length];
for (int i=0;i<word.length;i++) {
  present[i] = word[i];
}
```

And sorry if my Java's bad... I've been using Javascript a whole log recently and I may have gotten mixed up.

Comment: I wouldn't really call them *pointers*, but rather *references*